# What does being closed means on linear subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading a linear algebra book; linear algebra done right by Sheldon Axler, and I can't understand this:

So I define $V$, a vector space, as $\{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3\}$, and $S$, a subspace of $V$, as $\{ -2, -1, 0, -1 , 2 \}$.

$S$ isn't close to addition because $-2 + -3 = -5 \notin S$, and it's also not closed to multiplication but it's a subspace as it follows the rules of being a vector space, am I wrong? if so why?

- it's my first math textbook and I'm a high school student, so please eli5 a bit
- sorry for my bad English

Comment: $V$ is not vector space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why? can you explain

Comment: What is the field over which you are trying define $V$ as  a vector space? Is it closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy say I'm defining my vector space over R, and R is closed under multiplication, does it make any difference?

Comment: $10$ is a real number and $3 \in V$. Is $(10)3$ in $V$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No, but why should it be?

Comment: @Abtinshahpoori . For $V$ to be a vector space $cv$ must lie in $V$ for all $c\in F$ and $v\in V$. Where $F$ denotes the field over which it is defined. Here you can see that even for the smallest possible field , $\mathbb{F_{2}}$ , you have $-3-2=-5\notin V$.  So you can forget about $\mathbb{R}$ as Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out. That being said, it is probably not a good idea to learn vector spaces before learning a little group theory or atleast binary compositions. After all a vector space is a group under addition.  Since you are in high school, I doubt that you have seen any group theory.

Comment: @Abtinshahpoori You should go back to the book and read the axioms of a vector space and then try and verify whether this set you defined satisfies them or not. After that it should be clear to you why it is not a vector space.

Comment: @Abtinshahpoori also you should be specific with your question. What is the exact line from Axler that you cannot understand. You can also provide us with a page number so that we can find out what exactly is the confusion you are having.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Thank you for your suggestion on Group theory, I'll study it before going deeper in linear algebra and this is not an example from the book this is just what I thought is a vector space because it follows every rule listed on 1.19 (page 12), and is there any other thing I should be familiar with before starting out with linear algebra?

Comment: @Abtinshahpoori Interesting book! I'm scanning it now. On page 12, Definition 1.18 specifies that addition "assigns an element $u+v\in V$..." This is what has been referred to here as "closed under addition." In your $V$, we have element $u=2$ and $v=3$, but nothing in $V$ to call $2+3$.

Comment: @ndhanson3 so we can't have 5 + { 1, 2, 3, 4 } = {6, 7, 8, 9} ? I taught he meant we add the 5 to all the numbers and then we put them back in the set, so my assumption wasn't true?

Comment: Thank you all for answering my question

Comment: @Abtinshahpoori Yes! But that $6,7,8,9$ needs to be in $V$. But then, you'd also need $10$...and $11$. etc. Then of course, we still have the issue of scalar multiplication, which is why vector spaces are always accompanied by an underlying field: in the book, it is always $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe where you messed up, as the previous comments stated, was that $V$ isn't a vector space. If $V$ was a vector space, and $S$ satisfies those same conditions, $S$ would also be a subspace. Another thing to note is that $V$ and $S$ only include integers. What if you multiply by a fraction? You could end up with a value which is neither in $V$ nor $S$.

Comment: but why isn't v a vector space? it follows commutativity as for example: 1 + -2 = -2 + 1, associativity as for example: (1 + 2) + 0 = 1 + (2 + 0), additive identity : 0 + 1 = 1, additive inverse: 1 + -1 = 0, multiplicative identity: 2 * 1 = 2, distributive property: 3(10 + 2) = 30 + 6

Comment: I think you have gotten a bit confused on what are the conditions for being a vector space. The scaling condition doesn't satisfy: take $-1\cdot\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$: that isn't in the set of $V$, therefore $V$ isn't a vector space.

Comment: Ok, so you're basically saying that there is another condition called the scaling condition, I've never seen this before are there other rules?, second so vector spaces can only be {0} or C? cause anything else won't work

Comment: Technically it's not one of the axioms, but it's one of the conditions for being a vector space. Also, C  isn't a vector space, for example, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. If we took $f(1+1)=f(2)$, we get $\sqrt{2}$, but $2f(1)=2$. Not all continuous functions are a vector space, however $\vec{0}$ is, satisfying all axioms, the adding condition, and the scaling condition.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, I think I finally understood it, what are the other conditions of something being a vector space other than being closed to addition and multiplication and also a question what do I need to study before continuing with linear algebra cause others suggested I study group theory

Comment: $V$ would also be a subspace, first satisfying the axioms, the two conditions you mentioned, but also $V$ must contain the zero vector.

I'm studying linear algebra myself, and I would also recommend group theory, but you may also study calculus and multivariable calculus. If you haven't studied them yet, I would recommend precalculus.

Comment: @Abtinshahpoori Linear algebra is a bit more visually intuitive then group theory so it may be easier to start there. I would recommend the [essence of linear algebra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) video series as an intuitive supplement to the more formal treatment you'll see in books.